# updating my customer table-sql

Tags: sql, oracle

Good morning all, am writing a code to update my customer table,

```
Update ALEKWE_CUSTOMER C
SET RECENTLY_PURCHASED= (SELECT  CASE WHEN (DATE_PURCHASED BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12) AND SYSDATE) THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
from ALEKWE_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT D
where C.customer_id=D.customer_id)
```

but it is bringing the error

```
Single query returning more than one row
```

is there a better way i can write this code?
thankks for your help

Comment: Your Subquery SELECT Stataement returns more than 1 row that's the error. 

try ato add `AND ROWNUM =1`

Comment: its still returning ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row

Comment: Your subquery returns more than one row, because the customer has made more than one purchase for 12 months. You have to add aggregate. See the comments below, both solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to find out if a customer has purchased something for a year then you can use max function ('Y' > 'N') to get exactly one row:

```
UPDATE ALEKWE_CUSTOMER C
   SET RECENTLY_PURCHASED = (SELECT MAX(CASE 
                                          WHEN (DATE_PURCHASED BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12) AND SYSDATE) THEN 'Y' 
                                          ELSE 'N' 
                                        END
                                       )
                               FROM ALEKWE_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT D
                              WHERE C.customer_id=D.customer_id
                            )
```

Comment: i want to update the customer table with a yes 'Y' or a No 'N' if if the customer date of purchase from the CUSTOMER PRODUCT TABLE is within twelve months.

Comment: I understood that based on the tables names:) so this query has to help you to update your table correctly since ('Y' > 'N') I have doubts about your decision to keep aggregated data in the table, this idea violates [the third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form) (simple speaking, you can't keep aggregated data in a table if you have relationships between tables) unless you write ETL procedures and the table RECENTLY_PURCHASED is a [Fact table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema#Fact_tables) of your [start schema](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_schema)

Comment: May be your way is to create a view based on both tables RECENTLY_PURCHASED and ALEKWE_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT, it will help you to prevent editing of the same data in different places

Comment: recently_purchased is a table and not a view, i tried MIN and it worked well, dont really understand ur code, more explanation would be very helpful]

Comment: This answer will miss customers who are not in the ALEKWE_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT table, i.e. who never bought anything...

Comment: thats ok, it means they did not purchase anything

Comment: This query:`with t as (select 'Y' id from dual union select 'N' from dual)select max(id) from t` will show you that 'Y' is bigger than 'N'.Inside of the function max you can put the cause case:`with t as (select 'Y' id from dual union select 'N' from dual) select max(case when sysdate between add_months(sysdate,-1) and add_months(sysdate, 1) then 'Y' else 'N' end) a, max(case when sysdate between add_months(sysdate, 1) and add_months(sysdate, 2) then 'Y' else 'N' end) b from t` This query checks two cases: if sysdate is between previous and next month and between next and the month after next

Answer (score 0):

You get the error message 'Single query returning more than one row' because some customers might have bought more than one product at different dates. So you could end up with a 'Y' and a 'N' for the same customer, which can't be decided by Oracle, hence the warning.

If you aggregate multiple purchase dates to the latest date, i.e. MAX(DATE_PURCHASED), the query will work:

```
UPDATE ALEKWE_CUSTOMER C
  SET RECENTLY_PURCHASED=(
      SELECT CASE WHEN (MAX(DATE_PURCHASED) BETWEEN ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE,-12) AND SYSDATE) 
                  THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END
        FROM ALEKWE_CUSTOMER_PRODUCT D
       WHERE C.customer_id=D.customer_id);
```

But I agree with @zaratustra that you probably shouldn't store the RECENTLY_PURCHASED in the customer table...